# Why do my Apple Calendar events "revert" or vanish?

Tags: calendar, bug

Frequently (about 10-20% of the time) new events that I create in Apple Calendar either lose information I've entered for them (e.g., go from having any info at all to being a default new even with the title "New Event" and no other content) or vanish altogether. This seems to happen most often if I have added a location to the event, and only happens with iCloud events (not, for example Google events or events with any other service).

Is this a known bug? If so is there a procedure for fixing it?